# method as callback

Tags: c++, templates, callback

I've implemented my callbacks with interface..

```
struct ICallback
{
  virtual bool operator()() const = 0;
};
```

and function for adding a callback

```
void addCallback(const ICallback* callback) { .... }
```

and use, callback is in some class

```
class BusImplemantation{
public:
    struct Foo : ICallback
    {
       virtual bool operator()() const { return true;}
    }foo;
    void OtherMethod();
    int OtherMember;       
};
```

But because callback is class(not function/method), I cant within callback access to OtherMethod and OtherMember. If callback would be not class, but only method than it would be possible.(inner class vs. method)

**I cant pass OtherMethod and OtherMember to callback as parameters.**

Is there any better solution for that? maybe with templates?

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::function`:

```
void addCallback(const std::function<bool()>) { .... }

class BusImplemantation{
public:
    bool Callback() { return true; }
    void OtherMethod();
    int OtherMember;       
};

BusImplemantation obj;
addCallback(std::bind(&BusImplemantation::Callback, obj));
```

Comment: g++.exe (GCC) 4.5.2, I am using specific compiler for embedded, I think these function bind() and function() are here not included. I get error: 'function' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

Comment: @Meloun did you include `<functional>`?

Comment: @Meloun it's in the standard library.  You might have to pass a flag to enable C++11 (`-std=c++0x`)

Comment: thats not allowed for my embedded compiler :-/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/bind/bind.html) for a bunch of alternatives on how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you do something like this instead:

```
typedef std::function<bool()> CallbackFunc;
void addCallback(const CallbackFunc callback) { .... }

class BusImplemantation{
public:
    struct Foo
    {
       Foo(member) : OtherMember(member) { }

       bool operator()() const { return true; }

       void OtherMethod();
       int OtherMember;       
    }foo;
};
```

Instead of making your callback an interface, make it use std::function to make it a function object (a Functor), and any extra data or methods that your functor needs can be a part of the functor class.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using callback objects instead of free functions is that you can associate arbitrary state with them:

```
class BusImplemantation{
public:
    struct Foo : ICallback
    {
       explicit Foo(BusImplementation &p) : parent(p) {} 
       virtual bool operator()() const;

    private:
       BusImplementation &parent;
    } foo;

    BusImplementation() : foo(*this)
    {
        addCallback(&foo)
    }

    void OtherMethod();
    int OtherMember;       
};

bool BusImplementation::Foo::operator() () const
{
    if (parent.OtherMember == 0) {
        parent.OtherMethod();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ICallback` interface  must have pointer to controlled class with base interface, assume it `BusImplemantation` and inside callback use this pointer.

```
struct ICallback
{
  virtual bool operator()() const = 0;
  void setControlObject(BusImplemantation* o)
  {
    obj = o;
  }
  BusImplemantation* obj;
};

class BusImplemantation
{
public:
    void addCallback(const ICallback* callback)
    { 
       callback->setControlObject(this);
    }
    void OtherMethod();
    int OtherMember;       
};
```

And use:

```
class SomeCb : ICallback
{
   bool operator()
   {
       obj->OtherMethod();
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thats not good enought for me, I have more classes with callbacks => BusImplemantation1, BusImplemantation2,...  I cant cast setControlObject to particular class.